# less/lesser/the least in different contexts

Tags: meaning

TWO PILES

There are two piles of money. One pile is worth 100 dollars, the other one is worth 200 dollars.

**I point at the pile of 100 dollars and say:**

> a)    This pile is of the least worth of the two.
>
> b)    This pile is of the lesser worth of the two.
>
> c)    This pile is of the less worth of the two.

*(I think **a** and **c** are wrong for sure. What about **b**?)*

Or

> d)    The money in this pile is the least of the two piles.
>
> e)    The money in this pile is the lesser of the two piles.
>
> f)    The money in this pile is the less of the two piles.

*(I think d is wrong for sure. What about e and f?)*

**I point at the pile of 200 dollars and say:**

> g)    This pile is of the most worth of the two.
>
> h)    This pile is of the more worth of the two.

*(I think **g** is wrong for sure. **H** is correct.)*

THREE PILES
2 If there were three piles, it would be:

> a)    This pile is of the least worth of the three.
>
> b)    This pile is of the lesser worth of the three.

I think that **a** is correct? What about **b**?

Comment: The rule is to use the comparative for two things, the superlative for three or more - _the younger of two sisters; the youngest of three_.

Comment: Kate, I always appreciate your answers. But this time you lost the focus. The question is about "less/lesser/the least" rather than about "younger". b) This pile is of the lesser worth of the two. OR

c) This pile is of the less worth of the two.

Comment: I expected you to work out for yourself that the same rule  applies: the _lesser_ of two things, the _least_ of three.

Comment: I think you are missing the point. The confusion arises with "lesser" and "less", but not with "least"

Comment: Well, you included sentences with _least_ among your examples! _This pile contains less money than the other. This pile is of a lesser value than the others_.

Comment: I am sorry, but you are still missing another point. I never said about "than the other(s)" - construction. b) This pile is of the lesser worth of the two. OR c) This pile is of the less worth of the two. OR This pile is the lesser of the two. OR This pile is the less of the two.

Comment: A native speaker wouldn't say any of these sentences. They would simply say “This pile has **less money** than that pile. ”This pile has more money than that one”. By saying "lesser of the two piles" it seems you are comparing one pile with the amount of money in two separate piles. It's confusing. There are only two piles then all you need is THAN + N/pronoun e.g. Warren is better than Connor (him) You wouldn't say Warren is the better of two players-it's unnecessary and could lead to misunderstandings.

Comment: Mari-Lou A it's irrelevant who would say what. The point is to study when LESSER is used rather than proclaim what natives would say.

Comment: By saying "lesser of the two piles" it seems you are comparing one pile with the amount of money in two separate piles - NO, you are wrong. It would be THAN not OF

Comment: It seems to me that you are confusing "lesser" with the comparative form of "little: It's *little*, **less** and *(the) least*. This car is worth **less** than that one. Out of all the cars you own, this [one] is worth the least. Look at the [Cambridge dictionary definition](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/lesser?q=Lesser) of **lesser** and the examples it cites.

Comment: little has two comparative forms or even three which are less, lesser and littler

Answer (score 1):

> There are two piles of money. One pile is worth 100 dollars, the other one is worth 200 dollars. I point at the pile of 100 dollars and say:

<s>a) This pile is of the least worth of the two.
b) This pile is of the lesser worth of the two.
c) This pile is of the less worth of the two.</s>

<s>Or d) The money in this pile is the least of the two piles.
e) The money in this pile is the lesser of the two piles.
f) The money in this pile is the less of the two piles.</s>

I point at the pile of 200 dollars and say:
<s>g) This pile is of the most worth of the two.
h) This pile is of the more worth of the two. (I think g is wrong for sure. H is correct.)</s>

**Two piles**: "This pile has the least/lesser (or greater/greatest) value." **Lesser/greater** is likely to be used in formal situations or in exams as it is a comparative; **least/greatest** is used in normal conversation and informally.

**THREE PILES** 2 If there were three piles, it would be:
<s>a) This pile is of the least worth of the three.
b) This pile is of the lesser worth of the three.</s>

“**Worth**” is not used and, as you see, all of them are poor English; none of them are idiomatic, and they all sound weird. There is no point saying “*of the two/three*” as the listener can see the piles.

**Three piles ($100, $200, $300)**

This pile has the least <s>lesser</s> or greatest <s>greater</s> value.

With three or more items, the superlative is always used.

Comment: First point, "of the most/least worth" is not poor English or if it is then all the examples in google are poor English. 1 For many times you have desired of me to know that which would be of the most worth unto you. 2 The second question of your Highness is this : What appears to be of the least worth , although it is of the greatest worth? There are many others.

Comment: Second point. You said: Two piles: "This pile has the least/lesser (or greater/greatest) value."" How is it possible or shall I say correct to use the superlative form with two objects? And that's exactly what you did by using "the least".

Comment: @user1425 1. Why are you using, as your examples, a form of English that died out in the 18th century? 2. Because people in general do. If you bother to read all of what I have written, the explanation is there. Have a look at https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5697/use-of-the-superlative-when-only-two-items-are-present#:~:text=Some%20prescriptive%20style%20guides%20insist,want%20to%20follow%20this%20rule.